# Nodejs 10: Why does DynamoDB put function giving success multiple times

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I am writing node js 10.x lambda function to put details into DynamoDB table.

> Below is code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var tableName="xyz";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    console.log("Event: "+ JSON.stringify(event));
    
    var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
        },
    };
    await db.put({
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: {
            userid: event.userid,
        }
    }, (error, data) => {      
        if (error) {
            console.log("error:"+ error);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Success");
        }
    }).promise();
    
    return response;
};
```

> I am getting kind on random number of success return
>
> Output execution 1

```
2019-11-07T07:03:45.388Z    f451dfc1-01ea-41d0-a998-945cb0f18be1    INFO    Success
2019-11-07T07:03:45.510Z    f451dfc1-01ea-41d0-a998-945cb0f18be1    INFO    Success
2019-11-07T07:03:45.511Z    f451dfc1-01ea-41d0-a998-945cb0f18be1    INFO    Success
```

> Output execution 2

```
2019-11-07T07:08:19.270Z    3ce51f5d-bbbc-4dd6-b46f-2149ee9bb9cf    INFO    Success
```

> Output execution 3

```
2019-11-07T07:08:27.410Z    2625bba5-b8e1-40e4-8704-7c0d486f6dff    INFO    Success
2019-11-07T07:08:27.431Z    2625bba5-b8e1-40e4-8704-7c0d486f6dff    INFO    Success
```

**
does anyone know the cause of this problem?

I am relatively new to node js 10.x. so please help me if I have missed something in code
**

Comment: How are you calling this ```handler``` funcation?

Comment: by using Test Events in AWS Lambda UI console

Comment: The random string you are referring for example `2625bba5-b8e1-40e4-8704-7c0d486f6dff` is a `awsRequestId – The identifier of the invocation request.`

Comment: @error404
I am aware of it and not referring to request identifiers. what I am referring to is number of Success messages after execution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064038/aws-lambda-function-triggering-multiple-times-for-a-single-event

Comment: you are using supplying a callback and promise at the same time, remove the call back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using a [callback and promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721972/aws-lambda-function-firing-twice-when-i-click-the-test-button) at the same time, remove the callback.

You can try something like

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: {
            userid: event.userid,
        }
    };

    try {
        const data = await dynamoDB.put(params).promise();
        console.log("Data: ", data);
    } catch(error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
}
```